# How to aggregate a column based on another column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database where I have data for companies coming from different sources. I wish to be able to select data for specific company information (fields) and merge them into a single record per company. I wish to do this without using a 3rd normal form storage so I can still have referential integrity. I also wish to do the merge operation dynamically, and without specific coding for columns.

Example of data and query:

```
create table test2.company(
identifier int not null
,name varchar(100) null
,marketcap int null --in millions
,field varchar(100) not null
);

insert into test2.company(identifier, name, marketcap,field) values
(1,'Apple',1, 'name')
,(1,'Aplle',1000000,'marketcap')
;

select * from test2.company;
```

--result

```
----------------------------------------------
| identifier | name  | marketcap | field     |
| ---------- | ----- | --------- | --------- |
| 1          | Apple | 1         | name      |
| 1          | Aplle | 1000000   | marketcap |
----------------------------------------------
```

Best I have come up with so far:

```
with x1 as (select
    c.identifier
    ,case when c.field = 'name' then c.name else null end as name
    ,case when c.field = 'marketcap' then marketcap else null end as marketcap
    from test2.company c
)
, x2 as (select 
    x1.identifier
    ,string_agg(x1.name,'') as name
    ,sum(x1.marketcap) as marketcap
    from x1
    group by x1.identifier
)
select * from x2;
```

--result

```
----------------------------------
| identifier | name  | marketcap |
| ---------- | ----- | --------- |
| 1          | Apple | 1000000   |
----------------------------------
```

As you can see, I've had to specifically code for the columns. Where a data type was a number, I had to use sum, vs string_agg.

Is there some way to do this that is generic?

Comment: Does this table have a Primary key? Why are `name` and `marketcap` both column names and data values? Are you confused by some EAV data model?

Comment: Identifier is a pseudo-primary key. My query is supposed to merge the two records with identifier = 1 into one single record. On that single record, I want to use the value out of the name column for the first record, and the address from the second.
I appreciate that I look like I am merging an EVA style value (field) and otherwise regular data, but I didn't show that here for clarity.

Comment: There is no such thing as *pseudo Primary Key* . Your `identifier` is not even unique, so it cannot be a candidate key. (it *could* be part of one)

Comment: In the full implementation it uses a foreign key relation to a column in another table that is unique. Like I said, I intentionally left out large areas of the overall design for the sake of brevity. Perhaps you could focus on the specific question, rather than getting stuck on schema concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, this is how genric it can get -

```
with x1 as (select
    c.identifier
    ,c.field
    ,string_agg(c.name, '') as name
    ,sum(c.marketcap) as marketcap
    from test2.company c
    group by c.identifier, c.field
)
select x.identifier, 
       (select name from x1 a where a.field = 'name' and a.identfier = x.identifier) as name, 
       (select marketcap from x1 b where b.field = 'marketcap' and b.identfier = x.identifier) as marketcap 
       from x1 x;
```